# How to add same layout multiple times at runtime

Tags: android

please help I am designing email like app.based number of emails layout number also changes during run-time please help me.

```
for (int i=10;i<14;i++) {
LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.veticaltoinsert);
View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.issuelayout, null);
child.setId(i);
lay.addView(child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The id of the child view can't set like that.
The below code is not tested.

```
// this part copied from somewhere in sf, I don't remember exactly
// random a new integer
private static final AtomicInteger sNextGeneratedId = new AtomicInteger(1);
// create a view id
public static int generateViewId() {
    for (;;) {
        final int result = sNextGeneratedId.get();
        //
        int newValue = result + 1;
        if (newValue > 0x00FFFFFF) newValue = 1;
        if (sNextGeneratedId.compareAndSet(result, newValue)) {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
// In this party, just use above method and optimise a bit.
private void something() {
    //....
    LinearLayout lay = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.veticaltoinsert);
    for (int i=10;i<14;i++) {
        View child = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.issuelayout, null);
        child.setId(generateViewId());
        lay.addView(child);
    }
    //
}
```